# MS Access Temp tables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am coding a vba access based tool and happened to see there are temporary tables in the table defenitions. As this tool will be importing huge logs files, I am thinking to delete at the end of each run. Does it has any impact on performance of the tool in long run?
Is there any simple cmd to clear the temp tables?

the temp table looks like
~TMPxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 2):

You can use a compact and repair after you're finished. That clears all temporary tables.

In my experience, performance tends to increase, not decrease, after a compact and repair. The process itself, however, can take a little time (typically tens of seconds on a ~100MB database, but dependent on a lot of factors).

Note that a compact and repair can't be executed from VBA within the database itself. You can toggle *compact on close*, however. I've also posted a workaround for that limitation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47848960/7296893), but I recommend not using it when not needed.

Comment: Thank you Erik. If I delete all temp tables from vba, will it so the same as "compact and repair"

Comment: @OkiToma Nope. Compact and repair does numerous other things, like rebuilding indexes, which reduces fragmentation thus increasing speed and reducing size of existing tables. It also removes uncommitted changes from the database that might otherwise hang around.